# Run a Process with Redirected File Paths in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, io

Is there a way to run a process with redirected file paths in .NET similar to what Sandboxie and DropboxPortableAHK does?

For instance, if the process wants to write a file at `C:\file.txt`, I want my app to make the process write to `C:\Sandbox\file.txt` instead.

Comment: Is your app a framework, API or something like this for that proccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com), here is an [example](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68274#612760) you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Since .NET sooner or later redirects the call to the underlying OS, you really can attach a hook and replace CreateFile()-like routines to modify paths.

[Detours Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours) might be what you need. It has some licensing issues, especially in 64-bit mode, so look for the free alternative like this: [DetourXS](http://dreaminpixels.net/detourxs-a-x8664-detours-library/).

The exact instructions on hooking the CreateFile/WriteFile/ReadFile are given here: [CodingTheWheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-online-poker-bot-6).

You just write the DLL with procedures like this:

```
// Our custom version of the CreateFile Windows API, having the same parameters,
// return type, and calling convention as the version of CreateFile provided by the OS.
HANDLE WINAPI Mine_CreateFile(LPCWSTR lpFileName,DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
                              DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecAttr,
                              DWORD dwCreateDisp, DWORD dwFlagsAttr,HANDLE hTemplate)
{
    // First, call the original CreateFile provided by the operating system.
    HANDLE hFile = Real_CreateFile(lpFileName,dwDesiredAccess,dwShareMode,lpSecAttr,
                                    dwCreateDisp,dwFlagsAttr,hTemplate);

    // Now, do whatever we want with the filename (lpFileName)
    /// e.g., redirect C:\test.txt to C:\MyApp\test.txt

    // Now, do whatever we want with the file handle (hFile)

    // Call the original CreateFile

    // Return the same value returned to us by the original API
    return hFile;
}
```

Comment: Umm, The question is about C# not C++.

Comment: Still, it's the thing that can be done on the OS level, not in the .NET/CLR environment.

Comment: So then the correct answer is "no you can't do that in .net".

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple at all, but basically you need to create a DLL in native code (C++ for example). This DLL hooks file and registry IO and redirects it to your sandbox directory. Then, you inject this DLL into the sandboxed process. The DLL will then hook the activity of this process.

That's the basic idea.